# Plotting window doesn't show up with pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm on OS X Mavericks. I installed Anaconda as my python environment. I tried to plot with `pylab.plot(X,Y)` with IPython and then a python app icon appears. But then nothing happens nor I see any plots!

This is what gets launched after running the command. But then nothing happens.

[image]

p.s. I'm new to python.

Comment: Did you call `pylab.show()` after you'd plotted your function?

Comment: @Ffisegydd Ops! thanks that showed the window!!!

Comment: @Ffisegydd Please post that as an answer.  Another option is to use `ipython --matplotlib` which has hooks set up to do interactive plotting nicely.